# How to integrate jms topic to feed Storm spout

Tags: java, stream, activemq-classic, apache-storm, jms-topic

I have an ActiveMQ topic provider. I need to feed the data received from that topic into the Storm topic. is there any way to do it directly or should I create intermediate queue and feed topic data into the queue and then pull the data into the spout. Which is the best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have went through the ptgoetz's [Storm JMS Examples](https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-jms/tree/master/examples) and made a solution to directly feed the topic data to a spout.

need to specify the topic in jms-activemq.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <amq:topic id="topic" physicalName="myTopic" />

    <amq:connectionFactory id="jmsConnectionFactory"
        brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</beans>
```

then we can create JmsSpout like bellow with the Jms Acknowledge Mode in session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE

```
JmsProvider jmsTopicProvider = new SpringJmsProvider("jms-activemq.xml", "jmsConnectionFactory", "topic");

JmsTupleProducer producer = new JsonTupleProducer();

JmsSpout topicSpout = new JmsSpout();
topicSpout.setJmsProvider(jmsTopicProvider);
topicSpout.setJmsTupleProducer(producer);
topicSpout.setJmsAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
topicSpout.setDistributed(false);
```